# Kohana 3.2.3 installing on PHP 5.2.17 giving error

Tags: php, kohana-3

I downloaded kohana from their site, and installing Kohana 3.2.3 on PHP 5.2.17, it giving error.

`The configured system directory does not exist or does not contain required files.`

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/vol/vhosts/dev.abc.com/httpdocs/folder1/system/classes/kohana/core.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php-5.2.17/pear') in /vol/vhosts/dev.abc.com/httpdocs/folder1/application/bootstrap.php on line 7

[image]

In install file when i changed the path for system folder from "syspath/kohana" to "syspath/Kohana" (capital K) it removes the error

any idea why the kohana-3.2.3 stable release has this issue, later i downloaded the same version from github and it worked. i noticed it has small-case folders in system folder.

Comment: I have the same issue. Kohana 3.2.3 is not workable in linux. I have downloaded https://github.com/kohana/kohana/tree/3.2/master and the system folder in ZIP is empty. In windows its working fine, but I need it for linux. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it with:
1. Open console
2. cd path/to/the/project
3. find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} +
4. Refresh the page